# Angular Server side form validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, validation, ngresource

I am creating my first angular app and have just finished setting up a form that uses ngResource to talk to my Rails web service. I found [this tutorial](http://solidfoundationwebdev.com/posts/server-side-validation-with-angular-js-rails) extremely helpful in getting my validation to work.

I do however have a small issue. When I submit the form for the first time, without entering any value, my web-service responds with a 500 error. If I then type in a single letter and resubmit, it responds with 422 (like it should). If I remove this letter and resubmit it once again responds with a 422 (like it should). Thus no error messages are displayed on the first null value submission but if I allow the system to return an error on purpose and resubmit a null value it behaves like it should.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
$scope.memberData = {};
$scope.create = function() {
    var error, success;
    $scope.errors = {};
    success = function() {
      $scope.memberData = {};
    };    
    error = function(result) {
      return angular.forEach(result.data.errors, function(errors, field) {
        $scope.form[field].$setValidity('server', false);
        $scope.errors[field] = errors.join(', ');
      });    
    };

   BetaMember.save({ beta_member: { email: $scope.memberData.email }}).$promise.then(success, error);

};
```

View:

```
<form ng-submit="create(memberData)" name="form" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="memberData.email"name="email" server-error>
  <span class="errors" ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="form.email.$error.server">{{errors.email}}</span>
  </span>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Join</button>

</form>
```

Directive:

```
appServices.directive('serverError', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){
      element.on('change keyup', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          ctrl.$setValidity('server', true);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**My Question**

Why would this cause the web service to render a server error (500) if I submit an empty form initially? After submitting a random value, that does not pass server validation and renders a 422 error (that is displayed in my form) and resubmitting an empty form, I get a 422 error stating that the field is required.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I have updated the question @pablochan.